# How to return a json object in Google Endpoints

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The way I'm doing right now is I have a response class with a string message and return a json string. On the client side, I parse the string to use it as a object. I was wondering if we can  simply return a json object rather going through the parsing part

what I use now:

```
class Response(messages.Message):
  resp = messages.StringField(1)
```

on the client side I will get something like this

```
{resp: "{"message": "sucess", "some_data":"data"}"}
```

and I parse the `resp` string. However, my desired response will be

```
{message: "sucess", some_data:"data"}
```

EDIT: Im aware of the option where we state each key under the message class, But my question is more towards returning any generic json object

Answer (score 0):

You can define 'message' and 'some_data' on the response class directly. eg:

```
    class Response(messages.Message):
        message = messages.StringField(1)
        some_data = messages.StringField(2)

    jsonDict = {"message": "success", "some_data": "data"}
    return Response(**jsonDict )
```

If you only have a json string, you will need to convert to a dictionary first:

```
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonString)
```