# Returning JSON as string from Google Cloud Endpoints in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-cloud-endpoints

Having followed the Cloud Endpoints guide, [Creating an API with Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api), I tried changing it very slightly to my own needs:

```
class JSONResponse(messages.Message):
    json_str = messages.StringField(1, repeated=False, required=True)



@endpoints.api(name='api', version='v1')
class JsonApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(None, JSONResponse, http_method='POST', name='test')
    def get_json(self, request):
        tmp_json_obj = {"name":"me"}
        tmp_json_str = json.dumps(tmp_json_obj)
        return JSONResponse(json_str=tmp_json_str)
```

In a Python shell, json.dumps returns a JSON string with `"` for key/value pairs, and `'` enclosing the entire string (good, valid JSON).

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"name":"me"})
'{"name": "me"}'
```

In an App Engine environment, for some reason, the entire string is enclosed in `"` and not `'` (bad, invalid JSON). I see this in the [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) for Google Cloud.

```
"{"name": "me"}"
```

I can overcome this by escaping `"` manually:

```
...
tmp_json_str.replace('"','\\"')
return JSONResponse(json_str=tmp_json_str)
```

And then on the client side, using JavaScript, I have to unescape `"`

```
unescapeQuotes: function(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
}
```

This feels hacking so I looked for a cleaner implementation.

There are surprisingly few SO Questions on returning JSON from a Cloud Endpoints: [How to return a json object in Google Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334600/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-google-endpoints). The answers focus on ensuring any proto RPC Messages are **well defined** and **match any JSON** they encapsulate.

I agree this approach is clean, but what if, like me, you don't know the structure of the JSON and therefore can only provide a very basic proto RPC Message to encapsulate a JSON string?

Comment: Did you hear about the Google JavaScript client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js, it will ease you interaction between your web app/front end and your Cloud Endpoints. No need to manipulate JSON, but JavaScript objects.

Comment: @3371862 - The problem is on the server-side where the API is defined and implemented, not in the client-size where it is consumed.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what the problem is, here. The entire string *should* be enclosed in double quotes--single quotes aren't valid JSON. Can you paste the raw output of what you're getting from the browser client you're writing?

Comment: @saiyr - You're right. Both the Sackdriver logging and browser logging were printing and enclosing it `"`. I have now successfully returned the JSON as a string and `JSON.parsed` it to an object.